# Help need identifying analyses methods

Tags: correlation, anova, repeated-measures

Any and all help would be much appreciated! I've detailed a bit of information below, but if I left anything out please let me know

My hypotheses are (info: NA= novel asssembly; S= selections or assembly piece):

1) H0: NA, and S will not affect the completion rates of the assembly tasks.
H1: NA, and S will affect the completion rates of the assembly tasks.

2) H0: Time to complete an assembly between, NA, and S will be the same
H1: Time to complete an assembly between, NA and S will be different.

3) H0: Completion rates for color-coded and non color-coded novel assemblies will
be the same.
H1: Completion Rates for color-coded and non color-coded novel assemblies will
be different.

4) H0: Time to complete an assembly between color-coded and non color-coded 
novel assemblies will be the same.
H1: Time to complete an assembly between color-coded and non color-coded 
novel assemblies will be different.

In my experiment, I have 3 independent variables at 4x3x2:
- Assembly difficulty (low, medium, high, very high) which I believe is an ordinal variable
- % increase in assembly pieces (0%, 25%, 50%) which I believe is an ordinal variable
- Color coded assemblies (color coded, not color coded) which I believe is a nominal variable
- I also gave participants a pre-test to measure their spatial rotation ability, I think this may be the 4th IV with 1 level, but I'm not sure what to type of variable it is.

I ran the study as a within-subects 4x3x2. I measured two dependent variables, completion time (coded in seconds) and completion rate which was a binary variable (success/failure). I used a complete counterbalanced design, similar to the one found here

At this point it feels like there are a ton of different methods I could use to analyze the data. I have some general ideas, but I don't feel like I know enough that I feel confident running the analyses and writing up the results. I'll bullet out what I'm thinking because bullets are easier:

- ANOVA for Assembly difficulty x completion time / completion rate
- ANOVA for % increase in assembly pieces x completion time / completion rate
- ANOVA for color coded/not color coded x completion time / completion rate
- rank all of the scores from high -> low and see if there is a correlation with pre-test scores and completion times/rates

I have an ok understanding of R (thanks to the seemingly infinite resources on the internet) and plan on using that as my tool for analyses.

I know there are quite a few tests that measure whether or not your data satisfies the assumptions required for particular methods. We never got too deep in these at school thus that's an area I know even less about. Any help in that department would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why do analyses for both completion time and rate, increasing the problem of multiple testing, if they are linearly related? Secondly, the above-mentioned approaches are valid as long as you are not interested in the interaction between the two factors: e.g. what if the effect of assembly difficulty depends on whether there is color-coding (and it probably does). To address that, you can try a two-way or three-way (to include % increase) ANOVA. Pre-test scores can be used as a covariate in the analysis but whether you can partition all these effects depends on the sample size. Here's a good discussion of model assumptions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933253/homoscedascity-test-for-two-way-anova